# Exception thrown while processing service call: Time is out of dual 32-bit range

Tags: rosbag, callback, rosservice, ros-service, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing a very simple implementation of ROS service. There are two nodes, server and client node and the only main variable is that I am using rosbags for streaming data used by callback method on server side. I am getting the following error on some callbacks -

```
Exception thrown while processing service call: Time is out of dual 32-bit range
```

Can someone throw some light on why am I getting this error and how can I fix this for my service callback to work properly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209452/exception-thrown-while-processing-service-call:-time-is-out-of-dual-32-bit-range/) by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 281 on 2015-05-18

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The exception is because Internally ros::Time objects use int64_t variables and cast to uint32_t when returning the result.  When a time value is negative, the value exceeds what an uint32_t variable can represent. The result is the exception you are seeing is thrown.

This sample code that generates the exception you are seeing.

```
try {
  ros::Time test = ros::Time::now() - ros::Duration(0.01);
}
catch(std::runtime_error& ex) {
  ROS_ERROR("Exception: [%s]", ex.what());
}
```

Possible solutions:

1. Wrap your code in try-catch blocks and deal with the resulting issues
2. Call toSec() on time/duration objects and do the math manually

### TL;DR

Here's where the exception is thrown (source [here](https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/blob/indigo-devel/rostime/src/time.cpp#L487))

```
void normalizeSecNSecUnsigned(int64_t& sec, int64_t& nsec)
{
  int64_t nsec_part = nsec % 1000000000L;
  int64_t sec_part = sec + nsec / 1000000000L;
  if (nsec_part < 0)
  {
      nsec_part += 1000000000L;
      --sec_part;
  }

  if (sec_part < 0 || sec_part > UINT_MAX)
    throw std::runtime_error("Time is out of dual 32-bit range");

  sec = sec_part;
  nsec = nsec_part;
}
```

This code is one of several places where the exception might be generated. Subtraction is implemented as "negative addition". (source [here](https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/blob/indigo-devel/rostime/include/ros/impl/time.h#L83))

```
template<class T, class D>
T TimeBase<T, D>::operator-(const D &rhs) const
{
  return *static_cast<const T*>(this) + ( -rhs);
}

template<class T, class D>
T TimeBase<T, D>::operator+(const D &rhs) const
{
  int64_t sec_sum  = (int64_t)sec  + (int64_t)rhs.sec;
  int64_t nsec_sum = (int64_t)nsec + (int64_t)rhs.nsec;

  // Throws an exception if we go out of 32-bit range
  normalizeSecNSecUnsigned(sec_sum, nsec_sum);

  // now, it's safe to downcast back to uint32 bits
  return T((uint32_t)sec_sum, (uint32_t)nsec_sum);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [crazyorc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20596/crazyorc/) with karma: 141 on 2015-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-05-29**:
The explanation is correct. However, I would use another solution as this exception is a sign of something going actually wrong unless negative time has meaning. So, the best would be, figure out, where the exceptions happen and check the time values/durations involved.

**Comment by [crazyorc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20596/crazyorc/) on 2015-05-29**:
Excellent point.  My experience bias blinded me a little.  Playback of rosbags has been the source of many of these exceptions for me.

**Comment by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) on 2015-07-02**:
I've had the same issue recently, running bags on a set of code that I know works.  Any ideas on how to determine which clock times are wrong? I'm using the usual

rosparam set use_sim_time
rosbag play --clock bagfile.bag

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-03**:
I'd just dump the actual time stamps. Usually it's something, where 12.0 is compared to 173939302.2.

**Comment by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) on 2015-07-03**:
Thanks, that did it.  It appears there was an issue using ros::Time::now().toNSec() to populate the pcl point cloud header.stamp using the latest everything in Ubuntu 14.04. Started happening about two weeks ago, will confirm versions and post elsewhere.

**Comment by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) on 2015-07-03**:
Found a cleaner answer, see [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/172730/pcl-header-timestamp/)

`#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h> ... pcl_conversions::toPCL(ros::Time::now(), point_cloud_msg->header.stamp);`

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2016-03-21**:
@crazyorc the example you provide does not cause any issues on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04.3 64 bit, ROS Indigo).

**Comment by [crazyorc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20596/crazyorc/) on 2016-03-28**:
@bit-pirate Consider yourself lucky!  A lot has changed in the past year for both ROS *and* Ubuntu but I don't see any changes to fix this. I would expect my example to still fail since I don't see any changes (rushed glance), but if it works now that's awesome.